# Rails missing after installing Oh My ZSH?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zsh

I've recently changed my terminal to use Oh My ZSH but for some reason when I try to run rails commands I get the following error:

```
/Users/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find rails (>= 0) amongst [bigdecimal-1.1.0, io-console-0.3, json-1.5.4, minitest-2.5.1, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.9.4] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1210:in `gem'
    from /Users/david/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@railstest/bin/rails:18:in `<main>'
```

Would anyone be able to help me with this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem, and it turned out to be that I hadn't moved an essential line from ~/.bashrc to ~/.zshrc. Putting it in at the end and reopening the terminal fixed the problem:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Answer (score 9):

For people using rbenv, you should move your rbenv initialization to ~/.zshenv as in http://coderwall.com/p/0o64yq?i=1&p=1&q=author%3Awilhelmbot

Answer (score 7):

Like mention first step is to add

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

If after adding this line of code if still not work check your export path.

Check your PATH (export PATH) in .zshrc and remove all references to .rvm within it. You should end up with something like this export
             PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/texbin

When installing oh-my-zsh it will look at your current PATH and fill your .zshrc with it, which also pulls .rvm environment. And you won't want that there since rvm should be handling it.

Comment: After removing the references do we then reinstall oh-my-zsh?

Answer (score 1):

For **rbenv** users

when you install omz (oh my zsh!), omz does two things

1. It copies the content of .zshrc into .zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh
2. makes new .zshrc

To solve the "Rails is not currently installed ", what you could do is copy the content of .zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh into the new .zshrc.

```
cd ~
cat .zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh >> .zshrc
```

After this restarting the terminal worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try these commands:

- rbenv which rails
- rbenv which gem
- gem env

2) If the environment problem isn't clear from that output, then:

- See if you have this file:

`$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm`

- Try to "source" it

Q: Just out of curiousity, what is "ZSH" and why did you decide to try it?

Q: I imagine it's compatible with "bash", correct?